# What can I use to preview Pantone tints?

Tags: pantone

is there a Pantone book that shows tint values  eg. `20%` or `40% of 021c`?  I have looked far and wide for a Pantone Tint Selector which I seem to recall was available many years ago but now I can't seem to find it.
How do you get around this problem of tint values?

Answer (score 6):

I guess [this pack](http://id.pantone.com/pages/products/product.aspx?pid=17&ca=1) is what you are looking for. It shows tints of all Pantone inks in 10% increments and some more, including reversed out text and some overprinting.

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for. Any idea where I can buy it?  noone in UK seems to sell it

Comment: honestly, no clue. but there's a 'find a dealer' button at the top of the linked page, that might help.